# Chrome keeps all versions of my hosted app/extension (takes up MB's). How tell it to remove old versions? To downgrade?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I noticed that Google Chrome has kept all the versions (unpacked) of my hosted app. Even though it's delivered (via the `update_url`) as a `.crx` file, in the extensions folder, it has 47 folders and every one of them is the unpacked/uncompressed files from my app.

1. Why does it do this?
2. Is there any way to tell it to delete old versions?
3. Does this space count against the app's allowable local storage/filesystem quota?
4. Since it has all old versions, can you also downgrade to a previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=126394, basically same issue.
2. No. But you can delete them yourself by dragging them to the trash.
3. The extension isn't kept in local storage or the HTML5 filesystem, so no.
4. No.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like they're trying to pass that bug off to DivX (which I have disabled), so it likely won't get solved. This is very bad if customers get large extensions/apps and won't even know to look in that folder for why they're losing space on their HD.

Comment: After ten years, the issue isn't yet solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all but the newest directory (e.g. version of an extension) using Zsh like this:

```
setopt extendedglob

for i in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Chromium/Default/Extensions/*(/)
do
    if [[ ${#$(ls -1 $i)} -gt 1 ]]
    then
        rm -r $i/*^(Om[1,-2])
    fi
done
```

The caret `^` is for excluding a pattern (requires `extendedglob` to be set), `O` sorts the resulting expansion in descending order and `m` is for modification time. `[1,-2]` matches all but the first globbing result.

Comment: You mean `rm -rf`?  And need to turn on `setopt extendedglob`

Comment: And what does the `^` do?

Comment: You're right, `extendedglob` needs to be set. But I'm not so sure that you necessarily would need to add `-f` to `rm`. I modified my answer and added some explanations about the globbing parameters.

Comment: What's strange is that I took out the caret and it worked either way :)

Comment: For bash, I cd'ed to the offending directory and did `IFS=$'\n'; rm -r $(ls -t | tail +2)` . The IFS part is probably not necessary given how Chrome names extensions.